# mysql - How to filter results without specifying the columns

Tags: mysql, select

It might sound silly but Im just curious.

I have a table named `posts`:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| body     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The values:

```
+----+-----------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title                 | body                                   | created             | modified            |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2 | A title once again!!! | And the post body follows. Tralalalala | 2013-06-03 13:13:44 | 2013-06-05 09:36:51 |
|  3 | Title strikes back    | This is really exciting! Not.          | 2013-06-03 13:13:46 | NULL                |
| 11 | Tomcat                | Tommy boy!!! FFF                       | 2013-06-04 16:33:22 | 2013-06-04 16:48:40 |
| 12 | FFD                   | dsfdsf                                 | 2013-06-04 16:48:56 | 2013-06-04 16:55:50 |
| 13 | fdf                   | dfdsf                                  | 2013-06-04 16:57:47 | 2013-06-05 09:36:54 |
| 14 | GGD                   | dsfdsf                                 | 2013-06-04 17:02:33 | 2013-06-04 17:02:33 |
| 15 | GG#                   | dsfdsfff322                            | 2013-06-05 09:36:20 | 2013-06-05 09:36:28 |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Let's say I want to search for row that has the value `Th` (not case sensitive) regardless of the FIELD. This is like making a quick search function.

Normally I would do something like : `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%Th%' OR body LIKE '%Th%'`

I did not include the other fields because obviously they are not gonna accept those values.

I wanna know if there's a shortcut to this? Like `SELECT * FROM posts LIKE '%Th%'`.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem with SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%Th%' OR body LIKE '%Th%'

Comment: @PSR Its not really much of a problem but just imagine if I have 10 or more columns its really annoying. I just wanna know if there's a shortcut and that will be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain old SQL you need to specify all the column names you wish to include.

If you want more search-box-like behavior, I'd suggest looking at MySQL's fulltext functions; see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Im looking forward to learn about full text search Im sure I can use it for advanced and complex queries.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL language is based on the presumption of the schema being known. Thus, there is no "search any column" type of functionality. How would it work against non-text columns? What about columns of different collations? Aside from the language not having a feature, specifying the columns expresses your intent to the next developer and that as much as anything should be an overriding consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have covered that you need to specify all the columns.  Here is an alternative formulation that is a bit shorter:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE concat(title, ' ', body) LIKE '%Th%'
```

If you are looking for an exact match, then you can do:

```
select *
from posts
where 'Th' in (title, body)
```

Comment: How about using LIKE? I tried select *
from posts
where 'Th' in (title, body) but it seems that it needs exact value

Answer (score 0):

No there is no shortcut for using a where clause. and specifying the columns. Otherwise the query engine can never know what to filter and what column to filter unless you specify them in the where clause.

If you want a custom shortcut - you can write a function which takes a single parameter (the search string) and returns the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't.

Not sure what your use case is... does this alternative approach work for your use case?

`mysql -u{user} -p{password} -h{hostname} {database_name} -B -e "{query}" | grep "{search_string}"`

It connects to the database and runs the specified query, returns query results in new lines, fields separated by tab stop. Then use Unix utility `grep` to filter returned rows.

Comment: Im not familliar with this one but thanks for the eye opener. Im using mysql -u{user} -p{password} -h{hostname} {database_name} to connect to remote server but Im not familliar with the rest of the commands.